# How to create a table with no borders using standard lightning-datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, lightning-datatable, lwc-dom

I'm trying to create a table "***With No Borders***" using standard **lightning-datatable** of **LWC**.

I'm referring to the pieces of codes given in https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#With-no-borders and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example.

One thing I have understood that I have to have  to see the magic.

I tried accessing thead using this.template.querySelectorAll('thead')[0] and adding class in it as

```
        this.template.querySelectorAll('thead')[1].class="slds-assistive-text";
```

But I couldn't achieve the desired result. So can anyone please help me regarding it? Let me know what I'm missing, or is it not possible to achieve this at all.

Note: I have defined  class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_header-hidden" at data-table component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the internal components/state of a component except through their public APIs. As such, it's not possible to do what you're trying to do. You would need to build your own custom datatable implementation.